# Solve ODE $y'(y'+y)=x(x+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve ODE $$y'(y'+y)=x(x+1)$$

I tried to remove $y'^2$ term by differentiate it wrt x and then replace value in hope that it will turn out some exact form but got stuck after
$$2y'y''-yy'+y''=x-x^2+1$$

How i proceed further or my method is wrong ?

Edit:
Exact problem

If $y'-x\neq0$ is a solution of the differential equation $y'(y'+y)=x(x+1)$ then y(x) is given by

1. $1-x-e^x$
2. $1-x-e^{-x}$
3. $1+x+e^x$
4. $1+x+e^{-x}$

Comment: It is a MCQ options are like $$1\pm x\pm e^\pm x $$

Comment: No only 4 out of these 8 combination ,

Comment: So there is some typing mistake in question , i wasted so much time figuring it out . But was my method correct ? Should I delete this question now ?

Comment: The left side should end in $...+yy''=...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $(y')^2+yy'-x^2-x=0.$ One can solve $y'$ in terms of $y$ and $x.$ Notice that the above equation is equivalent to $(2y')^2+2y(2y')-4x^2-4x=0=(2y')^2+2y(2y')+y^2-(y^2+4x^2+4x)=(2y'+y)^2-(y^2+4x^2+4x),$ hence $(2y'+y)^2=y^2+4x^2+4x,$ implying $y^2\geq-(4x^2+4x).$ Notice that $4x^2+4x=4x^2+4x+1-1=(2x+1)^2-1,$ so $y^2\geq1-(2x+1)^2.$ This allows us to say that $2y'+y=\pm\sqrt{y^2+(2x+1)^2-1}.$